# Can't connect React frontend to server side Flask-socket.io, CORS ERROR

Tags: reactjs, flask, socket.io

This question in particular and many similar to it have been asked before but those solutions are not working for me, So I am posting this question again

React Front end Front end log :

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOaQQ2g' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOaQDio net::ERR_FAILED
```

python flask_socketio backend log :

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOaQQ2g HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

backend code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Frontend code :

```
import './App.css';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(socket.connected);
})

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Solutions which I have tried,

using flask_cors library,

setting cors_allowed_origins to "*" OR "http://localhost" OR "http://localhost:3000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and found that reverting the client-side React socket.io-client to version 2.3.0 did the trick.

So, uninstall socket.io-client:

```
yarn remove socket.io-client
```

Then install legacy socket.io-client:

```
yarn add socket.io-client@2.3.0
```

Then in your React client js:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
```